# Inconsistent event firing/capture in JavaFX 8

Tags: event-handling, javafx-8

Somewhat new to UI and JavaFX.

The following code snippet creates a JavaFX Circle (representing a logical switch), which is placed into a GridPane. The runtime behavior is very confusing.

On a MouseClick event, I simply want to indicate the selected switch (Circle). This is the *parent.setSelectedSwitch(this);* call. Sometimes it works for all of the Circle nodes. Other times, it seems like there is no event being generated, leastways, the registered event handler doesn't seem to get it. I tossed in the *println()* just to see if the event handler is being entered.

I am working in the IntelliJ IDE (if that makes a difference). On one run, everything will work just fine. Exit the app and re-run (without any code changes), and some of the Circle nodes do not appear to generate events.

Has anyone else experienced this?

```
private void generateCircleGraphic() {
    graphicCircle = new Circle();

    graphicCircle.setRadius(10.0);
    graphicCircle.setStroke(Paint.valueOf("BLACK"));
    graphicCircle.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
    setMouseEventHandler(graphicCircle);
}

private void setMouseEventHandler(Circle circle) {
    circle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        System.out.println("LogicalSwitch --> " + logicalSwitch.name());
        parent.setSelectedSwitch(this);
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `this` here? I.e. on which object is `setMouseEventHandler` being invoked? (Probably you will need to create and post a [MCVE] to get help with this.)

Comment: *this* is the logical switch object, which is represented by the Circle node.

The GridPane is populated with 55 Circle nodes, each representing a unique logical switch. Most times, all 55 Circle nodes receive MouseClick events (supported by seeing the *println()* output.

Sometimes, some of the nodes do not seem to receive MouseClick events. Which nodes do not receive the events seems somewhat random, and no code is being modified between runs.

I am hoping not to have to generate/post a working example, as their is a mix of FXML and procedural nodes.